# Connect IR sensor switch to light up and turn fan on when detecting human

Tags: switches, infrared, fan, button, direct

I want my store room light and fan to turn on or off automatically as people enter or leave the room. My current setup in the store room is a lighting control on off by the normal switch.
For the light it would be quite straight-forward I guess. But the fan, not so. It used to be controlled by controller or switch buttons. So I have to bypass this and find the way to connect it to the IR sensor.
Please refer to this issue from my question here:
[Bypass start button on bladeless fan to make fan start when power on](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/570414/bypass-start-button-on-bladeless-fan-to-make-fan-start-when-power-on)

I have bought most of the items on the above question and answer except for the IR sensor. I am looking at this one:
https://www.lazada.sg/products/ac85-265v40mm-pir-infrared-ray-motion-sensor-switch-time-delay-adjustable-ceiling-mode-detector-switching-intl-i242397960-s371815747.html?spm=a2o42.searchlist.list.26.5d202118WTW2Rj&search=1
And here is how it is connected as I google on the internet:
[image]
Now my remaining challenges would be finding the right component and way to connect them together.
And here is my understanding of how to connect things together.
[image]
I still don't know how to connect the rest of the IC pins and would it be safe to connect 220V to these components ?
Could anyone help me to figure out these so I can start to order and make it works ? Thank you !

Comment: Do you have a schematic or datasheet for the PIR motion sensor?

Comment: It would be good if you can make a simple schematic with explaining only the connections with no other pictures. Additionally do note that most PIR sensors are good at detecting movement and not presence, in other words a PIR sensor based switch would just turn off if there isnt a lot of movement in field of view.

Comment: @StarCat : All I have is the info on selling page. But I managed to find out some similar sensor with the photo as (updated in my question).

Comment: @NoumanQaiser : Sorry for my bad drawing. The reason I use real photo is to illustrate the real connection with this (so I will not understand wrongly and spoilt the device). So the above PIR is it good enough for my purpose, where human standing in that very small store room will got lighting and fan then when he leave everything turn off ?

Comment: (1) Be aware that you've chosen a **motion** sensor and not a **presence** sensor. It will turn off if the person stops moving. (2) The output is mains voltage AC. You can't feed that directly into low voltage (DC) electronics. You would need a relay energised by the sensor.

Comment: Tks for the inputs @Transistor ! Can you suggest a complete working solution that I can follow?

Comment: Tks for the inputs @Transistor ! Actually presence sensor is the best but only if it is similar cost, otherwise motion sensor could be ok since people go into that small store room will do something instead of stay still there, so I think it won't be a big issue. Btw, can you suggest a complete working solution that I can follow?

Comment: You can't mix AC (>100VAC) and DC (<6VDC) devices, they will explode and catch fire. Seriously, just get a simple AC fan and be done with it.

Comment: Any AC fan I also need to by pass the press on off button. I have 3 fans at home and I want to make use of them instead of throwing them away and buy 3 new ones, is that reason valid @rdtsc ?